# ng-table multiple template filters using coffeescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, ngtable

I'm using AngularJS, ng-table and coffeescript together and would like to create a multiple template filter within coffeescript and pass it into my angularjs template.

I have a name & surname combined column which I would like two filters for 'name' and 'surname'.

So far I have it working like so;

```
      <td data-title="'Customer'" sortable="'fullname'"
        filter="{'name_cont': 'text', 'surname_cont':'text'}" >
```

But I would like to define this filter in my AngularJS controller like so

```
   $scope.nameFilterDef = {
     name: {
       id: "text",
       placeholder: "Name"
     },
     surname: {
       id: "text",
       placeholder: "Surname"
     }
   }
```

And clean up my template by using that filter like so;

```
      <td data-title="'Customer'" sortable="'fullname'"
        filter="nameFilterDef" >
```

When I call the filter like this though no filter boxes appear.

**Update**

If I put {{nameFilterDef}} on the page I can see my filter hash getting passed in.

Comment: At first glance it looks like the **filter** attribute is not parsed as an angular expression. Did you try it as `filter="{{nameFilterDef}}"`?

Comment: Yes I did try that, I get the error; Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'nameFilterDef' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{nameFilterDef}}] starting at [nameFilterDef}}].

Comment: You could test your code by ng-repeating `nameFilterDef` in your template. If it turns up empty, means that the template `$scope` is not as you expect it to be. Could you create a plunker or jsFiddle?

Comment: If I use nameFilterDef in a ng-repeat I get my filter printed on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this html markup works for you...

```
<td data-title="'Customer'" sortable="'fullname'"
    filter="{'name_cont': 'text', 'surname_cont':'text'}" >
```

Then this code should work as well:

```
 //use this
 $scope.nameFilterDef = {
     'name_cont': 'text', 
     'surname_cont':'text'
  }
 //instead of this:
 $scope.nameFilterDef = {
 name: {
   id: "text",
   placeholder: "Name"
 },
 surname: {
   id: "text",
   placeholder: "Surname"
 }
}
```

-

```
 <td data-title="'Customer'" sortable="'fullname'"
 filter="nameFilterDef" >
```

Here is a working example in codepen:
[Passing filter from the controller as an object](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVMbwY)

Also if you provide working code in  plunker, codepen or jsFiddle, it would be super helpful.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried what you suggested there and it didn't work. It must be something deep within my setup I think. Maybe the rails asset pipeline is getting in the way, or coffeescript, or the version of AngularJS I'm using

Comment: I've figured out that I'm running a version of ng-table which doesn't allow this functionality. So I'm in the middle of upgrading that.

Comment: I've now got passed a few bugs and upgraded to 0.5.5 of ng-table and your answer works nicely, thank you.